# Target specific words and add class using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using ACF with WordPress, and across the site in various locations the word "Homeless" may be entered. When it is, I want to target the word "Homeless" only, and change it's colour.

I know I can target divs that contain the word with `contains()` , but how do I add a class to the word only and not the div?

```
$("h2:contains(homeless)").addClass("new-class");
```

Comment: you need to wrap that word in a dom element first then add a class to that

Answer (score 0):

You can actually replace the text using another HTML element with having the class `new-class` and then replace the HTML of `h2` with the new generated HTML.

```
$(function() {
  $('h2:contains(Homeless)').each(function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).html(function(i,text) {return text.replace(/homeless/gi, '<span class="new-class">Homeless</span>')});
  });
});
```

You should iterate over the elements to manipulate every element instead of targeting the collection at once. See the snippet below..!

```js
$(function() {
  $('h2:contains(Homeless)').each(function(index, elem) {
    $(elem).html(function(i,text) {return text.replace(/homeless/gi, '<span class="new-class">Homeless</span>')});
  });
});
```

```css
.new-class {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Homeless Heading</h2>
<h2>Another Heading</h2>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however it doesn't seem to be working for me in my WordPress site. Do you think this has anything to do with the word "Homeless" being inputted using ACF? It's not hard written into the HTML.